# Update recyclerview item

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to update recycler view item when it is pressed.
I load data to recycler view and I would like to change the way view looks if it is pressed, notifyDataChanged would not work because I'm not changing data, I want to change the view, for example I have created custom recycler view item layout where I have button with visibility=gone and when item is pressed I would like to set visibility to visible

Comment: which language you are using ?

Comment: kotlin or java?

Comment: you will need to store the state of change somewhere otherwise it will cause problems after recycling views.

Comment: you have to have a field in your data for your view change. Else it would end up with multiple or different view changing issue. So have a field and based on the field change the view. So, you can achieve it by notifyDatasetChanged()